# mySQL: duplicating multiple records via temporary table, how to preserve autoincrement index?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, copy, temporary

I wish to duplicate a selection of records in a mySQL table.
The pk of the table is an autoincremented int.
I want to do this with one set of mysql queries (for performance reasons).
It seems like the fastest way to do this is to put the results of the selection into a temporary table,
make any changes needed, and reinsert the records back to the original table, like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1234 ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE column='my selection';
# do updates in temp1234; (altering FK's mainly)
INSERT INTO a_table SELECT * FROM temp1234;
```

But when I try to do this i get an error for duplicate PKs.

Now, I realise that I could alter the INSERT with SELECT query to exclude the pk/ID column, but as I am proceduraly generating these queries across multiple tables for a large data copying function, i want to avoid having to supply column names.

What is the best way around this problem?

Comment: Hmm, I just discovered you can supply 0 as the pk value and it will generate the sequence number..  Maybe that is the solution?

Comment: Yes.. It is the solution